# Trigger event when google maps fusiontable layer is loading or finished loading?

Tags: javascript, events, google-maps-api-3

I'm loading in quite a lot of data from a fusion table using Google Maps Api. I'm adding the data as a layer to the map using the code below (code not relevant has been omitted)

```
function initialize() {

    var tableId = 'xyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxy';
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.522416,-0.11673),
      zoom: 9,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

   var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer();

   google.maps.event.addDomListener(
        document.getElementById('checkbox_id'),
        'click', 
        function() { filterMap(layer, tableId, map); }
   );

}

function filterMap(layer, tableId, map, generated) {

   var the_where_query = generate_where()

   layer.setOptions({
     query: {
        select: 'geometry',
        from: tableId,
        where: the_where_query
       },
     options : {suppressInfoWindows:true}
   });
}
```

My issue is that there is a big gap between clicking on the the checkbox and the data appearing on the map. I want to be able to listen for an event somehow so that I can

1. Display a loading div element when the user clicks the checkbox
2. When layer.setOptions has returned hide the loading div element.

I understand how to do the DOM work with the div, I just can't seem to find a good way of telling if the query has returned from the fusiontable lookup (which can take 1 - 2 seconds sometimes)

Comment: For KMLLayers, the `status_changed` event was added to specifically address this issue. Looks like you would need to file a feature request so that similar functionality can be added to Fusion Tables. https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?q=apitype:Javascript3

Answer (score 0):

You can put a listener to capture if its loaded. `status_changed` event is created for this.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'status_changed', function() {
 --your code here
});
```

Or, you can use `properties_changed` event which will be fired after it is loaded.

Comment: Does `status_changed` fire on fusion table layers? It's not in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks but as Chad says, this doesnt fire with Fusion tables.